# Where Can I Find Old Versions Of Veritas NetBackup?

Tags: netbackup, legacy

I have a Veritas NetBackup 3.4.1 installation running on Solaris 2.6.  I have a requirement to add some Windows 2000 Server systems to this backup system.

Does anyone know where I might find the install media for a compatible Windows client?

I do appear to have spare client license capacity, so I'm as close to "legal" as I'm going to get (Symantec will not support installations this old, or client platforms this old, for any price).

And before anyone asks: The version of NetBackup is required because of the age of the clients (AIX 4.x, Solaris 2.6, HP/UX 10i) and the server it is installed on.  The clients are not upgradable because they are reference systems for a legacy software product that is installed in some very large customers.  Upgrading to -current (or even merely less-bangy-rocks-togethery) revisions is not an option.

Comment: If you can't find anything, I'd consider using Clonezilla or similar. Something's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried eBay? For ridiculously out-of-date software, I've seen it used before to good effect.

http://shop.ebay.com/?_from=R40&_trksid=m570&_nkw=Veritas+NetBackup&_sacat=See-All-Categories

Looks like there are a few auctions currently.

Comment: Took a while, but someone I contacted through eBay was able to hook me up.  Thanks for the lead.